# StyleGAN 2 images completely black after Tick 0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am training StyleGAN 2 on my own dataset - https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2

It works fine on a single P100 in Google Colab, but when I move the model to Vast.ai and try it on multiple GPU's an odd issue happens.

Everything works up to Tick 0, and after Tick 1, the fake images all come out completely black.

My environment:

- Tensorflow 1.15
- CUDA 10.0

My training command:

```
python3 run_training.py --num-gpus=4 --data-dir="/root/data/" --config=config-f --dataset=images1_tf --mirror-augment=true --metrics=none
```

In rare instances it works and generates proper fakes, but if I interrupt the training with ^C and resume again, then it starts generating the all black images.

I have tried changing datasets, tried it with different machine instances, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with 2 GPUs (GTX 1080 8GB cards in my case) running Tensorflow 1.15 and CUDA 10.2...  It would train for exactly 1 tick as you mentioned, and then all subsequent fakes would be a pure black image.  On a whim, I upgraded my Nvidia driver from 440 to 450 which also bumped CUDA up to 11.  It then began working and generating proper images after tick 1.